# Problema con tarea JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

> A partir de este codigo como podria hacer que: Si el nombre ingresado está en blanco dejará de pedir notas y que si el nombre ingresado está en blanco dejará de pedir notas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nota[] = new int[11];
    String nombres[] = new String[10];


            }
        }
}
```

}

> 

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Disculpa, tal vez no me explique. Con la primera parte me refiero al código que coloque ahí. Necesito saber si a partir de ese código puedo realizar las consignas y si no como. Gracias.

Comment: Todo es posible, por favor agrega que has intentado para seguir con la segunda parte.

Comment: La consigna es clara: debes verificar si el nombre está en blanco y hacer tal cosa, y si no está en blanco debes hacer tal cosa... ¿Qué has intentado para hacer lo que se te pide y qué errores o dificultades tienes? Te pusieron el ejercicio para que aprendas a verificar cuando una cadena está en blanco y para que aprendas a comparar valores. Si te lo damos hecho no investigarás, no aprenderás.

Comment: Lo que necesito es, saber como hacer que identifique cuando esta en blanco. Ya que creo que lo podría hacer con un if pero no se como y ahí parte el problema. Busco tutoriales o ayudas pero no encuentro por eso accedo a esta plataforma.

Comment: Crees que lo podes hacer con un if... lo intentaste? o sea, probaste usar un if para chequear si la cadena esta vacia o no?

Comment: A ver, soy principiante. Si, lo intente con un if pero no se como hacer para que chequee si esta vacía o no. Manejo el for, if-else, switch, entre otros pocos y no se me ocurre como hacer que lo chequee en blanco.

Comment: Y por eso, es que hay documentacion de todas las funciones y del lenguaje ;) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty().. empeza con eso, y luego anda avanzando desde ahi... y si lo intentaste con un if, agrega como lo intentaste, asi podemos corregir que es lo que estas haciendo mal...

Comment: Bueno! Muchas gracias por la atención, para cuando tenga algo hecho edito la publicación así me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro si entendi, pero podrias hacer algo asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int nota[] = new int[11];
String nombres[] = new String[10];
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);


    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
        nombres[i] = leer.next();
        if (nombres[i] == "") {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
        nota[i] = leer.nextInt();
    }
    

    for (int i = 0; i < nota.length; i++) {
        if (nota[i] >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Alumnos aprobados");
            System.out.println("Alumno: " + nombres[i] + " Nota: " + nota[i]);
            leer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Aunque no estoy seguro si es lo que buscas, ya que se estaria creando un nuevo campo igualmente, una mejor solucion podria ser esta:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int nota[] = new int[11];
String nombres[] = new String[10];
String nombre;
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);


    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
        nombre = leer.next();
        if (nombre == "") {
            break;
        }
        nombres[i] = nombre;
        System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
        nota[i] = leer.nextInt();
    }
    

    for (int i = 0; i < nota.length; i++) {
        if (nota[i] >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Alumnos aprobados");
            System.out.println("Alumno: " + nombres[i] + " Nota: " + nota[i]);
            leer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Otra recomendacion es que saques el System.out.println("Alumnos aprobados"); del ciclo, para que solo se imprima una unica vez, y una recomendacion mas util, es que deberias crear un nuevo objeto llamado "Alumno" con atributos nombre y calificacion, asi seria un codigo mas estructurado, tambien te recomiendo el uso de List. El leer.close(); deberias ponerlo una vez acabado el primer ciclo, ya que ahi solo estaria cerrandose si algun alumno paso (y en cualquier caso, se estaria cerrando mas de una vez, si es que mas de uno paso, no pasa nada, pero esta mal).

Edit: despues de leer tus comentarios me di cuenta cual era tu problema, la utilizacion de next();, por eso aqui te dejo un codigo adaptado a esta situacion especifica utilizando nextLine();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nota[] = new String[10];
    String nombres[] = new String[10];
    String nombre;
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);


        for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
            nombre = leer.nextLine();
            if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            nombres[i] = nombre;
            System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
            nota[i] = leer.nextLine();
        }

        leer.close();

        System.out.println("Alumnos aprobados");
        for (int i = 0; i < nota.length; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(nota[i]) >= 7) {
                System.out.println("Alumno: " + nombres[i] + " Nota: " + nota[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fue lo que intente anteriormente, pero lo que necesito es que el programa se finalice al no poner nada. En cambio al hacer esto el programa solo pasa de linea.

Comment: entonces utiliza return; en vez de break;, o tambien puedes usar System.exit(0);

Comment: Probare y te afirmo

Comment: El return; no me funciono,  me explicarías como funciona el System.exit(0);?

Comment: Creo que ya se a que te refieres, el problema es que estas usando "next();", podrias intentar con "nextLine()" y tendrias un mejor resultado, edito mi respuesta una vez mas

Comment: Ya lo intente, pero sigue a la parte de nota

Comment: Revisaste el codigo?

Comment: Espera que lo corrijo, cuando lo tenga te lo paso por aqui.

Comment: Ahora si, perfecto muchas gracias.

Comment: Ahora si, una pregunta mas. Si tendría que poner un limite de 1 al 12 ¿Seria asi? `if (nota > 12) {

              System.out.println("Ingrese un numero valido");

               return;
              `

Comment: Si, el if seria abajo de System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");, al igual que con el nombre te recomiendo crear otro int para verificar el valor, te recoiendo usar el nombre "nota", y a tu arreglo ponerle el nombre "notas" la condicion seria if(nota < 1 || nota > 12) { return; }

Comment: no, si lo que quieres es que se repita hasta que ingrese un numero valido, en vez de que se detenga el programa, tienes que poner otro ciclo adentro, algo como while (nota < 1 || nota >12) {System.out.println("Ingrese un numero valido"); nota = leer.nextLine(); }, no estoy muy seguro de que funcione, pero algo asi seria la logica que necesitarias, en cambio si quieres que el programa se detenga dejando un ultimo mensaje, si seria como tu mencionas.

Comment: No lo consigo, te paso lo que hice?

Comment: creo que esto ya sobrepasaria el problema de la pregunta principal y la gente que pudiera tener la misma pregunta en un futuro se podria empezar a confundir, creo que deberias hacer otra pregunta, intente contactarte privado para resolverte tus dudas pero me parece que no se puede, tambien soy nuevo en stackoverflow

Comment: Cuando pongo mi ese codigo "if (nota > 12) {                System.out.println("Ingrese un numero valido");                 return;" me pone "The operator > is undefined for the argument type String, int"

Comment: Ok, solo hare una nueva pregunta ok? Gracias por la atencion,

Comment: eso es por que lo cambia por una cadena para que funcione el nextLine();, debes usar Integer.parseInt(nota);, exactamente como lo hice en el ciclo que muestra los alumnos que pasaron